# How can I stop a For loop in C++ when two conditions are met?

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am trying to get my for loop to stop running once two conditions are met. the `n` counter is not giving me an issue. I basically would like the loop to stop running once `totalSum` is equal to itself (or within a certain margin of itself) after the loop has started. *Im a beginner at coding and new to this site so I apologize in advance*. for testing purposes on anyones behalf, i'll include the code in its entirety.

**I will provide more info from here on**. my code runs as it should, although during the looping, the values being calculated become to large and I get something saying `nan` or `inf`. after printing out `totalSum` and such. I see that I get the value (correct sine calculation) repeated once or twice, but after that the number keeps being incremented or decremented by the loop . Once my loop finally ends after 100 times I get the aforementioned `nan`/`inf`.

```
long double sine(double x)                                       
{
long double totalSum = 0.0;

for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    int plusOrMinusSign = pow(-1, n);
    long double num = pow(x,(2 * n + 1));
    long double den = factorialtest(2 * n + 1);
    totalSum += (plusOrMinusSign * num / den);
    cout <<plusOrMinusSign<<" "<< x << "^" <<(2*n+1) <<"/"<< (2 * n + 1)<<"! = " << totalSum <<endl; //testing purposes
}
return totalSum;
}
```

whole program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>    //used for pow indicated in comment with "^"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

long int factorialtest(int x) //calculates factorial
{
long int factorialNum = 1;
for(int count = 1; count <= x; count++)
    factorialNum = factorialNum * count;
return factorialNum;
}

long double sine(double x)                                             
{
long double totalSum = 0.0;

for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    int plusOrMinusSign = pow(-1, n);
    long double num = pow(x,(2 * n + 1));
    long double den = factorialtest(2 * n + 1);
    totalSum += (plusOrMinusSign * num / den);
    cout <<plusOrMinusSign<<" "<< x << "^" <<(2*n+1) <<"/"<< (2 * n + 1)<<"! = " << totalSum <<endl; //testing purposes
}
return totalSum;
}

double cosine(double x)                     //returns cos of x
{
double totalSum = 0;

for(int n = 0; n < 100; n = n + 2)
{
    double num = pow(x,(n));            // ^ used pow here, does the power of x to the n value above
    double den = factorialtest(n);      //used my own factorial program here, multiplies n by factorial of n
    totalSum = totalSum + ( num / den);
}
return totalSum = 0;
}

double tangent(double x) {      //returns tangent
return sine(x) / cosine(x);
}

double secant(double x) {       //returns secant
return 1 / cosine(x);
}

double cosecant(double x) {     //returns cosecant
return 1 / sine(x);
}

double  cotangent(double x) {   //returns cotangent
return 1 / tangent(x);
}

int main() {

double x;

cout << "Input number to find sine: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Sine of " << x << " is " << sine(x) << endl;


}
```

Program calculating radians btw. Example of what is happening below using 1 for x. "Sine(1)"

```
-1 1^63/63! = 0.841471
1 1^65/65! = 0.841471
-1 1^67/67! = -inf
```

After a certain point it gives me that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: TL;DR - you know that you can have a boolean expression as the condition in the loop, as in `for (x = 0; x < 100 && y != z; ++x)`?

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. And yes I know that I can have true or false expressions which is what I initially tried to do. Which was  `for( int n = 0, totalSum = 0; n < 100; ++n; totalSum != totalSum)` but I know for is a pretested loop and would not run because it would be equal to itself already. And also that it's written incorrectly, but that's due to my ignorance.

Comment: what do you want to use as second condition?

Comment: everything between the two `;` is your expression.  Write like this: `for( int n = 0, totalSum = 0; n < 100 && totalSum != totalSum; ++n )`  (EDIT:  FYI: totalSum != totalSum won't be true - so fix your logic.  but that's what you just asked for, so I'm just following your lead here.)

Comment: I want to use `totalSum` as the second condition to stop the loop before the error occurs. and to the prior response, I read your question wrong. So no I don't understand how that will work but I will educate my self by looking up the definition of those operands.

Comment: Change your way of thinking.  There is no "second condition" there is simply one condition that is composed of a logical "and" expression.  (cond1) && (cond2).   Which becomes (n<100) && (totalSum != something)

Comment: Ok I see what the `&&` is doing. So basically it can't be out of the `;`. I will try this now!

Comment: Understood, I am new so I apologize again. Although I greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Also be careful with running sums of doubles and equality comparison.  You may find that you never hit an exact `totalSum == something` due to floating point precision.  Hopefully you write something like `totalSum < something`

Comment: "*once totalSum is equal to itself (or within a certain margin of itself)*" It's really hard to figure out what this could possibly mean. Something is always equal to itself.

Comment: During the loop, `totalSum` reaches its correct value and stays that way for multiple loops. So what I mean is basically when the value repeats itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the factorial function is defective - it will overflow for a surprisingly small input, 21! will overflow a 64 bit signed integral type.

What you are observing is undefined behaviour that’s manifesting itself as returning modulo a large power of two, which is zero since even quite a small factorial will be a multiple of a power of two.

That division by zero gives you an Inf (-Inf if the numerator is negative), under IEEE754.

You could fix your algorithm by simply multiplying the previous coefficient by a value that’s a function of the iteration step, but note that the built in trigonometric functions are not evaluated using this method so this exercise is purely academic.

Your actual question: you can have multiple conditions as a stopping conditional: the use of && and || is common.

Comment: I don't have to actually write the factorial function as that is someone else's job in my class. if you can explain to me the effect in that piece of code I would appreciate that. Because Im actually not sure how its defective(code wise). because I would like to have that running properly before I submit my work.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too closely at your code, you could have something like:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10 && j < 10; i++, j += 2)
{
    std::cout << "i: " << i << " j: " << j << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking there are 2 ways of interrupting any conditional loop.

#### 1 - You meet some criteria where the loop is not valid anymore:

```
while( myConditionIsTrue() ) 
{
    ...
}
```

where `myConditionIsTrue()` is anything that can be evaluated as not 0 or a boolean. This can be something as simple as `true` for an infinite loop, or `x == y` for a simple condition, or something more elaborate as `x == y && a != b`, or even a method call that will return something to continue or break the loop.

I showed you a `while` loop, but a `for` loop is just the same, where the `for` is in fact:

```
for(initializationCode(); myConditionIsTrue(); thisCodeRunsAtTheEndOfEachIteration()) 
{
    ...
}
```

#### 2 - You explicitly break out of the loop:

Using the keyword `break` lets you interrupt any loop at any given time, use it if you encountered a situation that's not expected, so it won't be part of the main condition of your loop, but be careful while you use it, since multiple exit points can make a code hard to follow and read.

```
while(x != y) 
{
    if(x < 0) 
    {
        break; // interrupts the while loop.
    }
}
```

Also there's the workd `continue`, which instead of interrupting the loop, just ignores the rest of the loop on this iteration and jumps to the next iteration, going to the begging of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You suffer from `factorial` overflowing already for small `n`. You should use a longer type but that wont fix the real problem. Consider that the increment you add in each iteration is actually a small number and that you can easily calculate the increment from the one in the previous step:

```
double increment = 1;
for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
    int plusOrMinusSign = n % 2;
    totalSum += (plusOrMinusSign * increment);
    increment *= x;                        // exponential part
    increment /= (n+1);                    // factorial part 
}
```

I didnt bother to get the maths correct, but I hope you get the idea. `x` is fixed and `n` grows only linear so there is little danger of overflow (especially as you expect `increment` to converge towards `0`).

I didnt get what you want to use as second condition. However, for the sake of completeness: Lets say the conditions are A and B then you break the loop via:

```
for (int i; A && B; ++i) { }
```

or

```
for (int i; ; ++i) {
     if (A && B) break;
}
```

there is at least a third way, but to avoid starting a discussing I leave it to the interested reader to find out :P.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I've misunderstood, but it sounds like you want to break out of the loop if the new value of `totalSum` is close to the old value. That means you have to be able to look at the difference between the new value and the old value. In this case, that's easy: the difference between the two is just `plusOrMinusSign * num / den`. So store that as a named variable and test it at the top of the loop:

```
long double adjust = 10000; // large enough that it won't quit on entry
for (int n = 0; n < 100 && my_epsilon < std::abs(adjust); ++n) {
    int plusOrMinusSign = pow(-1, n);
    long double num = pow(x,(2 * n + 1));
    long double den = factorialtest(2 * n + 1);
    adjust = plusOrMinusSign * num / den;
    totalSum += adjust;
    cout <<plusOrMinusSign<<" "<< x << "^" <<(2*n+1) <<"/"<< (2 * n + 1)<<"! = " << totalSum <<endl; //testing purposes
}
```

You'll have to decide what the value of `my_epsilon` should be; that determines how small the difference has to be to exit the loop.

And while I'm here, `int plusOrMinusSign = pow(-1, n)` is not a good way to toggle the sign; that exponentiation is going to be slow. Instead, initialize that value before the loop:

```
int plusOrMinusSign = 1;
```

and then, at the end of the loop body, just toggle it:

```
plusOrMinusSign *= -1;
```

or put that change in the loop increment:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 100 && my_epsilon < std::abs(adjust); ++n, plusOrMinusSign *= -1)
```

That last one is probably distasteful to some folks.

Comment: so with "my_epsilon" is that just a place holder for `totalSum`, or does that need to be replaced with a value. `(int n = 0; n < 100 && 0.00001 < std::abs(adjust); ++n)`? im unsure of the format that should be used here, or something like `(int n = 0; n < 100 && totalSum < std::abs(0.00001); ++n)`

Comment: @Kyronsk8 -- I put in `my_epsilon` with the assumption that it would be a named constant. You can replace it with `0.00001`, as in your comment, or you can leave it there, and give it a value outside of the loop: `const long double my_epsilon = 0.00001;`. Generally, the latter approach is preferable because the name (and you can probably pick a better one) tells you what its purpose is, while the value alone doesn't say as much. You'll often see this phrased as "don't use magic numbers".